# ConcurrencyKit ck_fifo_mpmc_dequeue and memory deallocation

Tags: concurrency, lock-free

I need to use a lockfree multi-producer multi-consumer queue, and I'm trying to use the [ConcurrencyKit](http://concurrencykit.org/) fifo_mpmc code. I managed to get the code working based on the sample from [regression code](https://github.com/concurrencykit/ck/blob/master/regressions/ck_fifo/validate/ck_fifo_mpmc.c#L84), except, there's no documentation on how to free the memory after dequeuing an entry from MPMC queue.

In particular, in the following function prototype,

```
CK_CC_INLINE static bool
ck_fifo_mpmc_dequeue(struct ck_fifo_mpmc *fifo,
             void *value,
             struct ck_fifo_mpmc_entry **garbage)
```

what exactly does `garbage` correspond to, and how does one free the memory of type `struct ck_fifo_mpmc_entry` that was allocated during enqueue? Following is the type declaration of enquque

```
CK_CC_INLINE static void
ck_fifo_mpmc_enqueue(struct ck_fifo_mpmc *fifo,
             struct ck_fifo_mpmc_entry *entry,
             void *value)
```

where one needs to allocate dynamic memory for `entry`, and my assumption was that `garbage` parameter of dequeue will just return a pointer to the enqueued memory. But if I just call free on `*garbage`, the code crashes. If I don't free, there's memory leak.

Unlike, other parts of CK, MPMC queue seems to have no documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Try the official mailing list next time, you'll be more likely to get a response!

Any dynamically allocated non-blocking data structure is going to require safe memory reclamation. In your case, you would also need to use ck_epoch or a similar mechanism in order to safely manage the memory of garbage, freeing it only when it is safe to do so.

The other option for you is to place garbage in a free list and re-use it at some safe point later (which is effectively what safe memory reclamation will do for you).